# Nested If-Conditions in Inform7

Tags: inform7

I am implementing a phone in Inform7 without any extension.

```
Calling is an action applying to one topic.
Understand "Call [text]" or "[text] call" as calling.
Carry out Calling:
    if the topic understood matches "Melissa":
        say "You are calling Melissa … 'are you fine?'";
        if player consents:
            say "good???";
        otherwise:
            say "I see!";
    if the topic understood matches "Dad":
         say "Hey boy";
    otherwise:
        say "beeeeep – [the topic understood] is not answering";
```

So if I call Dad the procedure works. But if I call Melissa, she is answering the question and when the player consents, the whole procedure fails:

```
>call melissa
You are calling Melissa … 'are you fine?'
yes
good???
beeeep -  
*** Run-time problem P39: Attempt to say a snippet value which is currently invalid: words 2 to 2.

  is not answering
>
```

Comment: @khelwood the problem seems to be, that he is running the last "otherwise" even though the condition "melissa" has matched …

Comment: Well that's certainly the case. If you don't want that, then your `if the topic understood matches "Dad"` ought to be `otherwise if ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have this construction

```
if A
   ...
if B
   ...
otherwise
   ...
```

Then the `otherwise` block will be executed in any case that `B` was not matched.

On the other hand, if you have

```
if A
   ...
otherwise if B
   ...
otherwise
   ...
```

then the `otherwise` block will be executed if neither `A` nor `B` was matched.

So in your case, your

```
if the topic understood matches "Dad":
```

should be

```
otherwise if the topic understood matches "Dad":
```

Comment: That's it! Thanks a lot!